# Load xml with clojure with XStream

Tags: xml, clojure, xstream

I am trying to load xml file using XStream api with clojure. This process don't works and i don't know what's happening.

I have a type defined in the namespace:

```
(ns myapp.domain.foo)

(defrecord Foo [value price])
```

And i have a function that import data from xml file using XStream.

```
(ns myapp.xml.xml-reader
 (:import myapp.domain.foo.Foo)
 (:import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream)
 (:import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver))

(defn load-from-xml
  [xml]
  (let [parser (XStream. (DomDriver.))]
    (.alias parser "Foo" Foo)
    (.fromXML parser reader)))
```

When i try to use this function for load a xml data to Foo type the following error accours:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException:myapp.domain.foo.Foo : myapp.domain.foo.Foo
```

This is my test code:

```
(deftest leitor-xml-test
   (let[ xml "<Foo><value>43.5</value><price>1000</price></Foo>"]
     (testing "should be possible to load xml"
  (let [ foo-list (load-from-xml xml)]
     (is (= (count foo-list) 1)))))
```

I dont understand why this happening. 
I think the problem may be the namespaces, because when i use this in repl work's fine.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

A record does not provide getters and setters for the fields. Is XStream able to serialise the fields directly?

Also you should require the foo namespace in the xml-reader namespace.

```
(ns myapp.xml.xml-reader
  (:require
    myapp.domain.foo)
  (:import
    myapp.domain.foo.Foo
    com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream
    com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver))
```

Otherwise the defrecord isn't generated.

Comment: hi, the xstream work's fine in the repl. Because of this i assume that it works without gets and setters. In my namespace already exist the declaration of require in xml-reader.